# React unable to resolve dependency tree npm install

Tags: reactjs

Estoy tratando de instalar material-table en mi app de react Js con el siguiente comando: npm i material-table
Pero me tira el siguiente error:
Al parecer para poder instalarlo necesito bajar la version de react?, actualmente tengo la 17.0.2 y según comprendo necesito bajar a 16.8.4. Como soluciono eso? o estoy entendiendo mal?

> npm i material-table
> npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
> npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
> npm ERR!
> npm ERR! Found: react@17.0.2
> npm ERR! node_modules/react
> npm ERR!   peer react@"^16.8.0 || ^17.0.0" from @material-ui/core@4.12.3
> npm ERR!   node_modules/@material-ui/core
> npm ERR!     peer @material-ui/core@"^4.0.0" from @material-ui/icons@4.11.2
> npm ERR!     node_modules/@material-ui/icons
> npm ERR!       @material-ui/icons@"^4.11.2" from the root project
> npm ERR!     peer @material-ui/core@"^4.12.1" from @material-ui/lab@4.0.0-alpha.60
> npm ERR!     node_modules/@material-ui/lab
> npm ERR!       @material-ui/lab@"^4.0.0-alpha.60" from the root project
> npm ERR!     2 more (the root project, material-table)
> npm ERR!   peer react@"^16.8.0 || ^17.0.0" from @material-ui/icons@4.11.2
> npm ERR!   node_modules/@material-ui/icons
> npm ERR!     @material-ui/icons@"^4.11.2" from the root project
> npm ERR!   17 more (@material-ui/lab, @material-ui/styles, ...)
> npm ERR!
> npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
> npm ERR! peer react@"^16.8.4" from @material-ui/pickers@3.2.2
> npm ERR! node_modules/material-table/node_modules/@material-ui/pickers
> npm ERR!   @material-ui/pickers@"3.2.2" from material-table@1.69.3
> npm ERR!   node_modules/material-table
> npm ERR!     material-table@"*" from the root project
> npm ERR!
> npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
> npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
> npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
> npm ERR!
> npm ERR! See C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\npm-cache\eresolve-report.txt for a full report.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\npm-cache_logs\2021-09-29T19_18_22_074Z-debug.log

Aqui mi package.json

```html
{
  "name": "myweb",
  "homepage": "https://mysite.mx/site",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@material-ui/core": "^4.12.3",
    "@material-ui/icons": "^4.11.2",
    "@material-ui/lab": "^4.0.0-alpha.60",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.14.1",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.2.7",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.8.3",
    "axios": "^0.21.4",
    "bootstrap": "^5.1.1",
    "chart.js": "^3.5.1",
    "cookies": "^0.8.0",
    "date-fns": "^2.24.0",
    "moment": "^2.29.1",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-autocomplete-hint": "^1.3.0",
    "react-chartjs-2": "^3.0.5",
    "react-data-table-component": "^7.3.1",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-export-excel": "^0.5.3",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.3.0",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.3",
    "sweetalert": "^2.1.2",
    "sweetalert2": "^11.1.7",
    "universal-cookie": "^4.0.4",
    "web-vitals": "^1.1.2"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```